# How to save the full path of file upload in php?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, laravel-5, filepath

I am using Laravel and I have a form that uploading a file. And I want to save the full path of that file in my database. Do you know how?

```
if($request->hasFile('alternate_add_file_path')) {
        $file = $request->file('alternate_add_file_path');
        $destination = 'files/';
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name =  $getCreateDate . '_' . str_replace('/','_',$M_USER_NAME) . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move($destination, $file_name );
}
```

This below is for the save into database

```
$M_FILE_PATH = $file_name;
```

I do not have an error though, just only the filename which saved into my database, not the full path.

Comment: You mean the path where you `move`d the file on the server? You can try with `realpath($file_name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a relative path to an absolute one (server side) you can use `realpath`. Eg.

```
$fullpath = realpath($file_name);
```